# 'paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk' has been abandoned.Composer(abandoned)

Tags: php, paypal

Hello I am updating a PHP project that was built several years ago and I encountered an error while running composer install.

The error message states that the `paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk package has been abandoned and is no longer maintained`. I have tried to find an alternative package, but none have been suggested. Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: The `paypal-checkout-sdk` uses mostly the PayPal v1 API. They do not have a v2 sdk. They do have a pretty expansive [documentation for v2](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/), but you'll have to build your own code to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comment answer, there were two REST SDKs for PHP

- for v1/payments - https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK
- for v2/checkout/orders - https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

Both of them are deprecated and should not be used for new integrations.

The [v2/checkout/orders API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) is still very much current, there just are no currently maintained SDKs (in any language) that implement it for you.  So to use it you need to implement the HTTPS calls yourself, typically by first creating a helper function to obtain an access_token (which can cache it for the allotted time if desired).

The [standard checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) gives a sample example backend in node.js (the index.js file), since JavaScript is the most widely-understood language; this is useful as a starting point to see how the simple backend routes to create and capture an order should work when paired with the frontend HTML/JS button approval. For more detail of what can be done from the backend see the v2/checkout/orders API reference itself.